# What is the reference to Kennedy in "Tomorrow Wendy" by Concrete Blonde meant for?

Tags: meaning, symbolism, song-lyrics, concrete-blonde

From the song "Tomorrow Wendy" by Concrete Blonde ([link to full lyrics](https://www.lyrics.com/lyric/1037224/Concrete+Blonde/Tomorrow%2C+Wendy)):

> Underneath the chilly gray November sky
>   We can make believe that Kennedy is still alive
>   And we're shooting for the moon
>   And smiling Jack is driving by

What does the reference to J. F. Kennedy mean here?

Comment: I've edited out the other stanzas of the song for brevity, I hope it's okay

Comment: Also asked on [r/AskLiteraryStudies](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskLiteraryStudies/comments/fil1be/what_is_the_reference_to_kennedy_in_tomorrow/).